# Exclude/Include a module from the app module and application build

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-builder

I am using angular 5 and i have the project structure as follows

[image: This is the image]

main-module is the base module and it has the most of the components and advanced module will have additional components . I have to develop two versions of the application. One basic and one advanced where

> **basic** -> **only main-module**
>
> **advanced** ->  **main-module + advanced-module**

When in basic version, the advanced module files should not be bundled when the application is built. Is there any way to dynamically import/Exclude the module based on some configuration. Please help.